# XPATH: Add a root node to a nodeset

Tags: xml, xpath

Consider the following XML-document:

```
<inst>
    <p>
        <n>1</n>
        <ins>
            <id>id_01</id>
            <pos>1</pos>
        </ins>
        <ins>
            <id>id_02</id>
            <pos>1</pos>
        </ins>
    </p>
    <p>
        <n>2</n>
        <ins>
            <id>id_01</id>
            <pos>2</pos>
        </ins>
    </p>
</inst>
```

I try to get the following output:

```
<inst>
    <ins>
        <id>id_01</id>
        <pos>1</pos>
    </ins>
        <ins>
        <id>id_01</id>
        <pos>2</pos>
    </ins>
</inst>
```

I wrote the following XPath-Expression:

```
//ins[id='id_01']
```

for getting the nodeset

I would like to create a complete xml document appending root node using Xpath

Comment: Better use xslt. I'm afraid it is not possible to query the result like you expect.

Comment: XPath *selects*.   XSLT *transforms*.    Your problem requires XSLT (or whatever language is hosting your XPath library) to further process the selected nodes.